# How to make VS Code highlight all occurrences of variable even with destructuring?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

```
interface APropsInterface {
    aVariable: boolean;
}

const AComponent = ({aVariable}: APropsInterface) => {
    console.log(aVariable);
    return <>...</>;
};
```

Above, there are 3 instances of `aVariable`:

1. Interface
2. Destructuring
3. Reference in the function

When I click on #1, only #1 and #2 are highlighted.

When I click on #2, all 3 are highlighted.

When I click on #3, only #2 and #3 are highlighted.

Is there a way to make it so that all 3 are highlighted no matter which one my cursor is on?